# ASP.NET MVC DataAnnotation - NullTextFormat

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to create a form, where the one field has default value, like this:

[image]

I created my view model class:

```
public class ApplicationDriverLicenseVM
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CDL Expiration Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "MM/DD/YYYY")]
    public DateTime? CDLExpDate { get; set; }
```

And View (by scaffolding):

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CDLExpDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CDLExpDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CDLExpDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

but in result no default text here:

[image]

why so and what I do incorrectly?

Comment: I believe you may be looking for a place holder. `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" }`

Comment: `NullDisplayText` is only respected when you use `@Html.DisplayFor()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NullDisplayText` is only shown on `Html.DisplayFor`, not on `Html.EditorFor`.

You can use the `placeholder` attribute of the HTML element, and add it to the `htmlAttributes` object of the `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CDLExpDate, new { 
        htmlAttributes = new { 
            @class = "form-control",
            @placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY" 
        }
})
```